# How can I convert this string representing a Date into a correct FireStore timestamp field?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an Angular application using Firebase Firestore database and I have the following problem with a Firestore timestamp field updating a date field.

Basically I have implemented the following update form:

[image]

Submitting this form it is called this component method that build an object using the form data and call the service method that will performs the update of the related object on FireStore DB:

```
  updatePatient() {
    console.log("UPDATE A PATIENT");

    console.log("FORM IS VALID: ", this.patientForm.valid)

    console.log("birthDate: ", this.patientForm.value.birthDate);
    console.log("birthDate type: ", typeof this.patientForm.value.birthDate);

    let birthDateAsDate: Date = new Date(this.patientForm.value.birthDate);
    console.log("birthDateAsDate: ", birthDateAsDate);

    let patientTobeUpdated: Patient = {
                                        completeName: this.patientForm.value.firstName + " " + this.patientForm.value.surname,
                                        birthDate: birthDateAsDate.getDate,
                                        ...this.patientForm.value
                                      };

    console.log("patientTobeUpdated created: ", patientTobeUpdated);

    this.patientService.updatePatient(patientTobeUpdated);
  }
```

This is my service method:

```
  updatePatient(patient) {
    console.log("UPDATE patient: ", patient);

    this.firestore
        .collection("patients")
        .doc(patient.UID)
        .set(patient)
        .then(function(docRef) {
          console.log("Patient successfully updated!");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error writing document event: ", error);
        });
  }
```

Before the update the object into my collection contains a timestamp field containing the patient birthdate as Firestore timestamp, this one:

[image]

The problem is that after the update it seems that the `birthDate` document field is updated as a string and it is no more a TimeStamp so it broke my application.

I was trying do convert the value retrieved from the form into a TimeStamp obtaining a date:

```
let birthDateAsDate: Date = new Date(this.patientForm.value.birthDate);
```

and then in the object construction:

```
birthDate: birthDateAsDate.getDate
```

but it is not working. After the update operation the `birthDate` document field still contains the value as string and it broke my application flow:

[image]

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I correctly convert the string value retrieved in the form into a FireStore TimeStamp as it was originally?

Comment: I do it this way new Date(MY_DATE_IN_STRING).getTime() but MY_DATE_IN_STRING is already formatted so it can be converted correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a timestamp type field in Firestore, you will have to provide either a JavaScript Date object, or a Firestore Timestamp object.  A string will not work.

The [JavaScript Date object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) does not accept MM/DD/YYYY form strings.  You will need a way to parse that string, which is not provided by JavaScript.  There are libraries that can help you with that, such as [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/).